# Why do I get no such file or directory error despite the file being present in the mentioned directory?

Tags: json, python-3.x

I am following a tutorial from a coursera course. In that tutorial I am supposed to get a json object and then load. I followed the same, where i downloaded the json file from the url using wget command in the terminal and then I have been trying to open the json file to load it and unfortunately I have been getting `No such file or Directory found` error.

I have tried using the relative path of the file I am trying to use with '''/sarcasm.json''' being the relative file and I have also tried to use the absolute path `/Downloads/jarvis/VA/sarcasm.json`. I am have the same error either way.

```
with open('/sarcasm.json', 'r') as f:
    datastore = json.load(f)
```

Either way I am having the same error '''FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:'''. I have read other similar questions and have followed the mentioned procedures where tthey have suggested to use relative path and I still have the error. I have checked and the sarcasm.json file is present in the mentioned directory`users/microbot/Downloads/jarvis/VA/sarcasm.json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/sarcasm.json` and `/Downloads/jarvis/VA/sarcasm.json` are both absolute paths. The first one means that the file is right *in the root directory* (`/`), and the second one - that there's a folder called `Downloads` in the root directory. None of that is the case, as the error messages show.

If you wanted a relative path, use just `sarcasm.json` while running the script from `/users/microbot/Downloads/jarvis/VA/` or use the full path: `/users/microbot/Downloads/jarvis/VA/sarcasm.json`.

Comment: Thanks, I have fixed it. I overlooked which folder my output terminal is in and its apparently in parent Directory. So now the error is fixed. Thanks for clearing out.